# Create reduced set of combinations with nextflow tuple channel

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I have a question regarding nextflow and how to process the following channel of tuples and two single elements:

```
tuple_ch = Channel.of([['a','a','a','a'], 
                       ['B','B','B','B'], 
                       ['m','m','m','m'], 
                       1,2])
```

How could I transform `tuple_ch` to look like this (so its now a list of tuples):

```
[['a','B','m',1,2],
 ['a','B','m',1,2],
 ['a','B','m',1,2],
 ['a','B','m',1,2]]
```

I would need an input like this for my next process in the pipeline.

Comment: It seems like a typo to me, but I considered both situations in my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, yes that was a typo. I edited my question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I should mention is that the first channel you created is not a 2-element channel. It's a single-element channel containing

```
[[a, a, a, a], [B, B, B, B], [m, m, m, m], 1, 2]
```

This is easy to verify. Just `.view()` your channel and you'll see it's a single-element channel as it has a single emission.

Anyway, if you want to convert that original channel of yours to the version you showed at the end you can use the [`transpose`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#transpose) operator:

```
tuple_ch
  .transpose()
  .toList()
  .view()
```

The output:

```
[[a, B, m, 1, 2],
 [a, B, m, 1, 2],
 [a, B, m, 1, 2],
 [a, B, m, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the transpose function :)

Comment: Channel operators are very very powerful! :D